# Get list of all roles in Netsuite

Tags: netsuite

Is there a way to get the list of roles that are available in an Netsuite account? I am working on a provisioning solution with Netsuite and I am very new to netsuite. if anyone can point to APIs where I can get list of roles (employee roles?), it would be helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A successful **Login** request to Suitetalk (Netsuite Webservices) returns list of all roles available. http://tellsaqib.github.io/NSPHP-Doc/class_net_suite_service.html#ae54779a9faa0c0be881b5ed284c5e8b3

Comment: Can this be updated to a link that has content, please?

Answer (score 4):

To view Roles list:

```
Go to Setup > Users/Roles > Manage Roles
```

There is a work around to get the list :

Create a saved search on the employee record with role in the search column (group) and then use search API to get this search result.

Comment: this is not API way of getting roles list

Comment: Hi Prason, I am not sure if there are APIs to directly search on the role record. I have suggested a workaround in the above comment.

Answer (score 1):

There is a REST role service that can retrieve all accounts, roles and domains available for a user:

```
URL: https://rest.netsuite.com/rest/roles

Headers:
GET /rest/roles HTTP/1.1
Accept: */*
Accept-Language: en-us
Authorization: NLAuth nlauth_email=johnsmith@xxxxx.com, nlauth_signature=****
```

For more details, see the [help documentation](https://system.netsuite.com/app/help/helpcenter.nl?fid=section_N2972111.html) (Netsuite login required).

Comment: Hi Michoel, I have 91 roles in my netsuite account but i am able to fetch only 28 roles according to the given API. Can you please assist me with the same?

Answer (score 0):

```
This is example  :  

$nsroleObject = new RecordRef();  
$nsroleObject->internalId = $roleId ? $roleId : $this->_accountInfo['nsrole'];  

$passPort = new Passport();  
$passPort->email = $this->_accountInfo['nsemail'];  
$passPort->password = $this->_accountInfo['nspassword'];  
$passPort->account = $this->_accountInfo['nsaccount'];  
$passPort->role = $nsroleObject;  

$loginRequest = new LoginRequest();  
$loginRequest->passport = $passPort ;  

$result = $this->netsuiteService->login($loginRequest);  
if ( !$result || !$result->sessionResponse->status->isSuccess ) {  
    return false;  
}  

// if success, update roles list    
$this->_wsRoleList = $result->sessionResponse->wsRoleList->wsRole;
```