# Get list of all roles in Netsuite using java ( using either direct approach or saved searches)

Tags: java, netsuite

I want to get list of all roles in netsuite.

I am using wsdl2java to generate client port and service from netsuite wsdl.

I can assign Access Role to Employee in Netsuite using UI. I can view the existing Role to the employee on UI.

I can search employees using saved searches but how can I get the Roles using saved searches.

Same question is asked at :
 [Get list of all roles in Netsuite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18612926/get-list-of-all-roles-in-netsuite)
but answer for this is given specific to PHP.

How can I achieve the same using wsdl2java classes ?

Comment: Hi Nitin, Did you find any workaround to achieve the above query.We are facing the same issue.